# Android studio - problem with no connected devices

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I checked a lot of ask about my problem, but nothing helped me out.
I tried to run my app on emulator, but everytime log cat display "no connected devices" error.

```
 org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:uninstallDebug'.
org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
Caused by: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First of all check if you have created any virtual devices by following steps.

Go to **Tools**-->**AVD Manager**

Then you can see the virtual devices.If you don't see any devices, create a new virtual device.You can use this  **+Create Virtual Device**  button at the bottom left corner.Then run your application and check.

### If that is not the case try this.

Click terminal option at the bottom left corner of the window and run following commands.

Command one: `adb kill-server`

Command one: `adb start-server`

Hope this will help you.